# Call function within function problem (Swift logic)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to call the likeIt function once the UIButton is pressed, but I cannot call that function. If I move the function outside, I lose the values that I need for the likeIt function. I use the TextPost struct from another file for this. As shown below I get an error when I try to call the function in the IBAction. I am clueless on how to solve this problem.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class textTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "textTableViewCell"

    @IBOutlet var textContent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var name:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var comments:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pbImage:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var time:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var liky:UIButton!
    @IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        likeIt()                                                //Use of unresolved identifier 'likeIt'
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        pbImage.layer.cornerRadius = pbImage.frame.size.width / 2
        pbImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "textTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }

    func configure(with model: TextPost){
        self.name.text = model.username

        if model.numberOfComments == 1{
            self.comments.text = "\(model.numberOfComments) Comment"
        }
        else{
        self.comments.text = "\(model.numberOfComments) Comments"
        }

        let url = URL(string: model.userImageName)
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pbImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }

        let start = model.timestampName.index(model.timestampName.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
        let end = model.timestampName.index(model.timestampName.endIndex, offsetBy: -9)
        let range = start..<end
        let cleanTime = model.timestampName[range]

        self.time.text = String(cleanTime)
        self.textContent.text = model.textName

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
//        let docRef = db.collection("posts").document(model.postID)
        db.collection("posts").whereField("hasLiked", arrayContainsAny: ["\(userID)"]).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err{
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")

            }else{
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if case document.documentID = model.postID {
                        let image = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        self.liky.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                        self.liky.tintColor = UIColor.red
                        print("loaded likes")
                    }else{
                        print("nothing")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func likeIt(){
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
            let docRef = db.collection("posts").document(model.postID)

            if self.liky.tintColor == UIColor.red{
                docRef.updateData([
                    "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["\(userID)"])
                ])
                print("removed like")
            }else{
                docRef.updateData([
                    "hasLiked": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(userID)"])
                ])
                print("added like")
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried just running it? Sometimes XCode glitches and shows an error like that and then if you run it it goes away

Comment: doesnt let me run it @fisch

Comment: The `func likeIt()` function isn't in the class's scope, it's only available within `configure(with model: TextPost)` function's scope as that's where it's defined.  If you want it valid anywhere in the class, move it into the class scope and out of the current function it's in.